# Dropdownlist in MVC required field with string Datatype Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a drop down list in cshtml:-

```
<div>
    Salutation
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.SalutationId,
        new SelectList(Model.SalutationsList, "SalutationId", "SalutationName"),
        "Please select one",
        new { style = "width: 200px;" })<br />
</div>
```

In my viewModel i have property without any annotations as Required:

```
public string SalutationId { get; set; }
```

Still the drop down list is required. I tried using the following:-

```
public string? SalutationId { get; set; }
```

The above is giving me an error as :-

[image: nullable error]

I am not sure on how to proceed with this.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you explain: "still the drop down list is required"?

Comment: Your not giving enough information. 1stly, there is an easier method using an `IEnumerable` data type property in your `ViewModel`. Populating that with hardcoded `SelectListItem`s. 2ndly, you can retrieve a list of data from your DB and populate the `DropdownList` with that. The questions I have... What value are you saving from the dropdown, `SalutationId` or `SalutationName`? Are these values hardcoded or extracted from a DB table?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use just `string`:

```
public string SalutationId { get; set; }
```

If it's not an answer, could you describe, where do u get an error, because an error message suggests only that change above.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a reference type and the default value for all reference types is `null`.

Remove the `?`, add the `Required` data annotation, and use it like this:

```
[Required]
public string SalutationId { get; set; }
```